# change font size of button on jquery dialog

Tags: jquery

I've got some simple dialog

```
$("#modal").dialog({
  autoOpen: false,
  height: 350,
  width: 600,
  modal: true,
  buttons: {
    Cancel: function() {
      $(this).dialog("close");
    }
  }
});
```

How to change the size of text in a button - `Cancel`?

Answer (score 1):

Edit your css like this;

```
 #dialog .ui-button-text {
     font-size: 15px; /* Or whatever smaller value works for you. */
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
#modal{font-size: 20px; } /*where #model is button id*/
```